# How to fix the missing libraries error in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, azerothcore

I'm setting up a new server, CMake 3.14.0-rc1 send me to a error message. i try some solutions post here but i dont find the correct one.

```
"CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL (missing: OPENSSL_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  src/cmake/macros/FindOpenSSL.cmake:184 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:92 (find_package)"
```

this is the message.
I add manually the missing entry but not work. (Windows 10 and OpenSSL version 1.1.1a not light installed.

thank you all can help me for a solution.

Comment: What do you mean by manually adding the entry? Adding  `OPENSSL_LIBRARIES` on the command line? Is it still set afterwards ? Does it exist? Shouldn't it find the headers as well? Did it work? Did you set `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` ?

Comment: Why not look at [FindOpenSSL.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake) to see where it searches on Windows (see `_OPENSSL_ROOT_PATHS`). Also try running with `--trace-expand`

Comment: CMake find the correct path for OpenSSL automatically. i just enter the missing OPENSSL_LIBRARIES with the Add Entry button on CMake

Comment: ***CMake find the correct path for OpenSSL automatically. i just enter the missing OPENSSL_LIBRARIES with the Add Entry button on CMake*** This probably means the version of openssl you are using is not supported by `CMake`  possibly something changed in the naming of the library or other generated files that does not match what the finder module expects.

Answer (score 1):

CMake automatically calls the function [`FindOpenSSL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FindOpenSSL.html):

> ### FindOpenSSL
>
> Find the OpenSSL encryption library.
>   This module will set the following variables in your project:
>
> `OPENSSL_FOUND`
>   System has the OpenSSL library.
>
> `OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR`
>   The OpenSSL include directory.
>
> `OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY`
>   The OpenSSL crypto library.
>
> `OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY`
>   The OpenSSL SSL library.
>
> `OPENSSL_LIBRARIES`
>   All OpenSSL libraries.
>
> `OPENSSL_VERSION`
>   This is set to $major.$minor.$revision$patch (e.g. 0.9.8s).

Yet `OPENSSL_LIBRARIES` is missing; it generally means openssl needs to be installed on your development environment. You'd generally need the devel package.

Comment: There is no "function" `FindOpenSSL`. What you cite, is from the description to `FindOpenSSL.cmake` script, which is processed by `find_package(OpenSSL)` call. The error log in the question post clearly states, that such call has been performed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev true, fixed.

Comment: so i need to open with notepad the file FindOpenSSL.cmake and set the correct path there?

Comment: ***so i need to open with notepad the file FindOpenSSL.cmake and set the correct path there?*** No you never change this file. You can set environment variables or cmake variables to tell CMake where you have installed openssl if it is not in the place the finder module is looking. You first comment for your question asked you if you set the `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` environment variable.

Comment: I just forgot to change x64 settings in CMake...thank you for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Click Advanced tab in Cmake and set Openssl_root_dir